# Use data in angular directive link?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How i can use data , which passed from controller to directive from tag attribute ?? Its show undefined in console .

```
App.directive('applist', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
'use strict';
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: {
           gamesList: '=',
       }.
       link: function(scope,attrs){
           console.log(scope.gamesList); //undefined
       }
    }
}])
```

And html:

```
<applist games-List="games">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in gamesList | groupBy: 'game.id'"> ... </div>
</applist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @ for getting String Values: 
Modified Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<applist games-list="games"></applist>
<script>
var App=angular.module('myApp',[]);

App.directive('applist', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
'use strict';
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       transclude:true,
       scope: {
           gamesList: '@',
       },
       link: function(scope,attrs){
           console.log(scope.gamesList); //games
       }
    }
}])
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get error in console after this ... 
 Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: game in gamesList, Duplicate key: string:p, Duplicate value: p

Comment: Are you using ng-repeat inside the directive. Can you make a jsfiddle for your code. Because the above piece of code is working fine in standalone mode

Comment: It was coming if we used = instead of @, and your question was about passing the data, make your question clear.

Comment: See the updated code for removing error. I have included transclude. Please check the angular documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You must change your tag to:

```
<applist games-list="games">...</applist>
```

Also, in angular, the camelCase in your attributes is used with a '-' in the html tag. And you forgot the 's' to the 'game'

Edit: As stated, the dot before link is making the directive break. Try:

```
return {
   restrict: 'E',
   scope: {
       gamesList: '='
   }, //change dot to coma
   link: function(scope,attrs){
       console.log(scope.gamesList); //undefined
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes its my mistake , but after this it still not working

Comment: @AroTonoyan works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/lwxBp6z2fMdTi0nP3Dou?p=preview (once you change the dot before link into a comma)

Answer (score 0):

To get data from directive attribute you can use below code

console.log(scope.gamesList);

Your directive will be

```
App.directive('applist', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
       scope: {
           gamesList: '@',
       },
       link: function(scope,attrs){
           console.log(scope.gamesList); //games
       }
    }
}])
```